# Create Case & assign Case Team Role JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript, case, case-teams

I have the following JavaScript code which creates a **Case** from an Opportunity, on button click.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
var myquery = "SELECT Application_Entitlement_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Id = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}' limit 1";

result = sforce.connection.query(myquery); 
records = result.getArray("records"); 

if(records[0]){ 
var relatedAccount = records[0]; 
try{ 
var recToCreate = new sforce.SObject("Case");

// select Case Record Type
var recordTypeQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Name,Id from RecordType where developername = 'WE_Application'");
var recordTypeQueryResult = recordTypeQuery.getArray("records");
recToCreate.RecordTypeId = recordTypeQueryResult[0].Id;

// select Queue as owner 
var queueNameQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Queue.DeveloperName, QueueId from QueueSobject where Queue.DeveloperName = 'Wex_Europe_Customer_Services'");
var queueNameQueryResult = queueNameQuery.getArray("records");
recToCreate.OwnerId = queueNameQueryResult[0].QueueId;

recToCreate.AccountId = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}'; 
recToCreate.Subject = '{!Opportunity.Name}'; 
recToCreate.Origin = "Customer Application";
recToCreate.Opportunity__c = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
recToCreate.User__c = '{!Opportunity.OwnerId}';

// select Entitlement from Account field
recToCreate.EntitlementId = relatedAccount.Application_Entitlement_ID__c;

var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]); 

if(result[0].success == "true"){
location.reload();
}
else{
alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + result[0].errors.message);
}
}
catch(e){
alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + e);
}

}
```

I need to update this code to include an element which assigns the current user to a **Case Team Role** called Requestor.

I've found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000009PZNIA2) code and tried to combine the two, to create the below. I'm new to JavaScript so (unsurprisingly) it hasn't worked.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

var myQuery = "SELECT  Application_Entitlement_ID__c  FROM Account WHERE Id = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}' limit 1";
result = sforce.connection.query(myQuery); 
records = result.getArray("records"); 

var roleName = "CaseRole",
var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM CaseTeamRole where rolename + "Requestor");
var crRecords = qr.getArray("records");
var rec = crRecords[0];

if(records[0]){ 
var relatedAccount = records[0]; 
try{ 
    var recToCreate = new sforce.SObject("Case");

    // select Case Record Type
    var recordTypeQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Name,Id from RecordType where developername = 'WE_Application'");
    var recordTypeQueryResult = recordTypeQuery.getArray("records");
    recToCreate.RecordTypeId = recordTypeQueryResult[0].Id;

    // select Queue as owner 
    var queueNameQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Queue.DeveloperName, QueueId from QueueSobject where Queue.DeveloperName = 'Wex_Europe_Customer_Services'");
    var queueNameQueryResult = queueNameQuery.getArray("records");
    recToCreate.OwnerId = queueNameQueryResult[0].QueueId;

    recToCreate.AccountId = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}';  
    recToCreate.Subject = '{!Opportunity.Name}';  
    recToCreate.Origin = "Customer Application";
    recToCreate.Opportunity__c = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
    recToCreate.User__c = '{!Opportunity.OwnerId}';

    // select Entitlement from Account field
    recToCreate.EntitlementId = relatedAccount.Application_Entitlement_ID__c;

    var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]);

    // add business requestor to Case Team Role
    var ct = new sforce.SObject("CaseTeamMember");
    ct.MemberId = "{!$User.Id}";
    ct.parentId= result[0].id;
    ct.TeamRoleID =rec.Id;
    alert('Logged In User:'+ct.MemberId);
    alert('Case ID:'+ct.parentId);
    alert('TeamRoleID:'+ct.TeamRoleID);

    var result = sforce.connection.create([ct]);
    alert('Successfully Added to Case Team');

    // check that Case has been created
    if(result[0].success == "true"){
        location.reload();
    }
    else{
        alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + result[0].errors.message);
    }
}
catch(e){
    alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + e);
}

}
```

On button click, the following error message is displayed and I'm not sure what's going wrong here?

> unexpected token var

Comment: If you can't see syntax errors in your JavaScript, paste it into this web site http://jshint.com/. Generally it does a good job of identifying the line number where the problem is (line 6 for 2 reasons in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might sound silly, you have used a comma instead of a semicolon in the below line

```
var roleName = "CaseRole",
```

replace it with

```
var roleName = "CaseRole";
```

once u go past this one, you might face error in the next line as well

```
var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM CaseTeamRole where rolename + "Requestor");
```

it should be

```
var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM CaseTeamRole where Name = 'Requestor'");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, my alert's telling me that Case Id is undefined [from line alert('Case ID:'+ct.parentId);] and then another returns 'Invalid parameter value'..

Comment: So I've added an additional alert below the line var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]); which also tells me that result[0].Id is undefined, is this the wrong way to fetch the Id or could it be something to do with the Case not having been inserted yet?

Comment: can u do an alert on error message immediately after the create.. alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + result[0].errors.message);

Comment: I've added the alert and it returns 'cannot read property 'message' of undefined'.

Comment: u shd start here and understand how to use the create calls and handle the results :  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm

Comment: In the end it was the upper case i in ct.parentId= result[0].Id; that was causing the issue, I've updated the code in my question to fix that. 5 hours wasted because of a single character!